# Kusto Caching (Azure Data Explorer)

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer, adx

I am trying to understand caching in kusto. I know Azure Data Explorer gives caching OOB. However, if I set the below properties while making a call to ADX, how it behaves? I don't see any difference with and without these properties. It returns the data almost with-in the same response time. Also, assume if I make the call at 8 where the cache for that specific query will be set to 2 hours. When i call the same query at 9 using the code with same properties, will kusto ignore the cache properties because there is a cache set already or will it reset the cache to 2 hours again from 9?

```
clientRequestProperties.SetOption(
    ClientRequestProperties.OptionQueryResultsCacheForceRefresh,
    true
);

clientRequestProperties.SetOption(
    ClientRequestProperties.OptionQueryResultsCacheMaxAge
    2
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. there are different types of cache in Kusto - the one controlled by the properties you included in your questions is the [query results cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/query-results-cache), which isn't enabled by default.

   - note that when you set `ClientRequestProperties.OptionQueryResultsCacheMaxAge`, you need to pass a value of type `timespan`, e.g. `"02:00:00"` (or `TimeSpan.FromHours(2)`) for a 2 hour period (and not `2` as you showed in your question).
   - note that when you set `ClientRequestProperties.OptionQueryResultsCacheForceRefresh` to `true`, you are forcing a cache refresh for a specific query, and cached results won't be used.
2. the more common type referred to is the one controlled by a [caching policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/cachepolicy). This is enabled by default.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also confirm this part of my question: ```Also, assume if I make the call at 8 where the cache for that specific query will be set to 2 hours. When i call the same query at 9 using the code with same properties, will kusto ignore the cache properties because there is a cache set already or will it reset the cache to 2 hours again from 9?```

Comment: as mentioned in the answer - your code forces the cache to be refreshed, so it won't use previously cached results. it will cache the results of the current execution, so that sequential ones (that don't force refreshing the results cache) will be able to use them

Comment: So, if I use just OptionQueryResultsCacheMaxAge, then cached results will be auto-refreshed after those many hours? Basically got confused with this MSDN documentation ````query_results_cache_force_refresh (OptionQueryResultsCacheForceRefresh): If set, forces query results cache refresh for a specific query. Must be used in combination with 'query_results_cache_max_age', and sent via ClientRequestProperties object (not as 'set' statement). [Boolean]````. It invalidates the purpose of "query_results_cache_max_age" if i have to use "query_results_cache_force_refresh"

Comment: Also, if i just set 'query_results_cache_max_age' in my code, when the query runs through my code for the second time, will it reset again or wait for the previous cache time set and ignores the second one? (I am asking this because the document is not that good as usual)

Comment: there's no "auto-refresh" of cached query results. the query results cache may only get populated when a query is run, if the caller specifies the 'max age' (or if it's defined as part of the workload group's query consistency policy)

Comment: I probably will explain with an example: At 5, I call the query through my code with Cache_max_age as 4 hours. So, now the results will be cached for next 4 hours (say till 9). If i call the same query trough my code again at 7, Will it cache the results for next 4 hours from 7 (till 11), or will it expire at 9 as per the first call made and ignores the cache_max_age came as part of the second call for the same query?

Comment: When the results cache is used - the query doesn't run, and results are taken from the cache. No new entry with modified results is set in the cache in this case.